# Получение UserId(ClaimsPrincipal) для любого пользователя

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Как я могу получить объект `ClaimsPrincipal` для любого пользователя, например с `UserManager`? Он мне нужен для получения id. Для текущего пользователя так : `var id = userManager.GetUserId(User);` 
мне нужно что то на подобии : 
`var id = userManager.GetUserId(userManager.Users.Where( x => x.UserName == "admin" ).First());`

В данный момент работает так:

`var UserId = context.Users.First().Id`

Или текущий вариант и так нормальный ?

Comment: Небольшая поправка по этому коду `userManager.Users.Where( x => x.UserName == "admin" ).First()` - `First()` выдаст `Exeption`, лучше использовать `FirstOrDefault()`, который вернет `NULL`. Также `Where` тут бесполезен, почти все LINQ методы поддерживают лямбду, то есть `.First(x => x.UserName == "admin")` выдаст тот же результат. Теперь по поводу вопроса: Если посмотреть в [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/dn468199(v%3dvs.111)), то можно увидеть методы `FindBy...`, что мешает найти нужного пользователя с помощью `FindByName` и далее узнать его ID?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо за ответ. Но я хотел бы узнать как воспользоваться методом `GetUserId`, и возможно ли это для любого пользователя